# How to check for multiple keys in a dictionary, and then do something with each of them?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, tastypie

I'm trying to do some TastyPie validation, but I'm relatively new to Python (and programming in general) and completely new to TastyPie, so help is welcome.

`bundle.data` is a dictionary, and I

1. Want to check the existence of keys in the dictionary then
2. Do some more validation for the value of each key.

Sample code:

```
class SampleClass(Validation):

    def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        errors = defaultdict(list)

        for number in (bundle.data['number_one'], bundle.data['number_two']):
            if number not in bundle.data:
                errors[number] = ['missing field']
            else: 
            # Do more stuff with number
```

What is the most pythonic way to go about this?

I think the `for number in....` statement and the `if number not in bundle.data` statement are redundant. Is that correct? How can I combine the check if both numbers are keys in the dictionary and assign them to a variable name so I can do stuff with both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not Tastypie problem. It's Python problem.

To check the existence use:

```
for key in [key1, key2]:
    if key not in my_list:
        # key not exist
    else:
        # key exist
```

And your code:

```
class SampleClass(Validation):

    def is_valid(self, bundle, request=None):
        errors = defaultdict(list)

        for number in ('number_one', 'number_two'):
            if number not in bundle.data:
                errors[number] = ['missing field']
            else: 
                value = bundle.data[number]
                # Do more stuff with number
```

> I think the for number in.... statement and the if number not in bundle.data statement are redundant. Is that correct?

This code has no sense. If key1 or key2 does'nt exist, then `KeyError` are raised.

> How can I combine the check if both numbers are keys in the dictionary and assign them to a variable name so I can do stuff with both?

```
if key1 in data and key2 in data:
    val1 = data[key1]
    val2 = data[key2]
```